# Run same Node.js App on IPV4 and IPV6 simultaneously?

Tags: node.js, server, ipv6, ipv4

I know when I have the hostname as "::" this means the same as "0.0.0.0" in IPV4.

```
    const express = require('express')
    const app = express()
    const port =80
    const host6 = "::";
    const host4 = "0.0.0.0";
    
   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.send('Hello World!')
    })
    
    app.listen(port, host6, () => {
      console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
    })
```

This App should now be accessible through IPV6 but als IPV4. But devices which don't understand IPV6 can not make the initial request over IPV6, so for them the App is not accessible.

How can I run this App on both IP versions on the same Port 80?

Comment: Omit the host entirely. `app.listen(port)`.

Comment: It is behaving the same: http://ipv4:80 not accessible http://ipv6:80 OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unconfirmed, but I would try to remove the host from the arguments passed to `app.listen` and only pass the port, `app.listen(port)`.

Express docs for [`app.listen`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen) state that

> This method is identical to Node’s http.Server.listen().

Node's documentation for [`http.Server.listen`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen) state that

> This method is identical to server.listen() from net.Server.

Node's documentation for [`net.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#class-netserver) states that

> If `host` is omitted, the server will accept connections on the unspecified IPv6 address (`::`) when IPv6 is available, or the unspecified IPv4 address (`0.0.0.0`) otherwise.

Comment: It is behaving the same: http://ipv4:80 not accessible http://ipv6:80 OK

Comment: $ sudo ufw status 
--                         ------      ---- 
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                   
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                   
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                   
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

Comment: Seems that my internet provider (router) does not support IPV4 - fml. I try to hide the pain. thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured out your issue.

Comment: I lost over 40h - one call to my internet provider clearified: extra $9 per month to have ipv4 - for another $20 a static IP, pain.